# A user without a name on SO?

Tags: discussion, bug

I just see a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180905/how-to-echo-php-variable-from-array#comment35453117_23180905) from a SO user but his name is seems to be blank or created by some special characters. Who is this *hollow-man* ? How one can create such named profile ?

Comment: I can see the following username next to the comment:  ̇̇̇. Seems to work in Chrome and Safari at least.

Comment: So, I guess this user got renamed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is a comment left by this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/790454/790454

His username is all special unicode characters, making it appear as if he has no username at all.

Comment: How did you find that ? And I guess it should not allowed to keep such name which makes difficultly for others sometimes.

Comment: Generally such usernames seem to be reset @Rikesh. At least the various instances I've seen. And the information is easily retrieved by inspecting the source.

Comment: @Rikesh: there *is* a link there; it is even clickable (in Chrome). It's just a very small link target.

Comment: My glasses tell me you are correct @MartijnPieters. Similar instance in the past had no visible characters at all. But still, annoying at best.

Comment: The username uses 3 [U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE](http://codepoints.net/U+0307) characters.

Comment: I would suggest adding a rule to disallow such usernames. Perhaps usernames could be required to contain at least *one* character that is neither whitespace nor a combining character nor a control code.

Comment: Why does it bother you so much @rmunn?

Comment: @Mark0978, because (as others are reporting) it screws up the clickability of the username link for most people, thereby harming the functionality of the site.

Comment: @rmunn: I disagree, instead I would suggest that the username link has a minimum width and height that would make it clickable no matter the user name. Personally, I find clicking on an hypothetical `a` or `c` as daunting, because the target is just so tiny; once the target has the minimum width of say 4 or 5 characters, then it matters not what's inside.

Answer (score 13):

Not long ago, this question was [asked on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229322/241526) when Meta.SE was still Meta.SO. The answer I gave there is still good.

The user has used a Unicode combining character. My Firefox browser does add the link decorations to the character but I can't click on it.

A quick examination of the HTML generated for the user link shows that the character used is `U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE`, which combines with what appears before it. Because it is a combining mark and because the text in the `<a>` link generated for the user name **begins** with this mark, it throws off Firefox (and maybe Chrome too) and makes the text of the user name either extremely difficult to select or maybe even impossible to select. (I sure can't select it. I had to select *around* it and cut and paste.)

So there is a name, just not one that is easily actionable.

Comment: Clickable in _my Firefox_ (28.0 on OS X 10.6.8).

Comment: How to identify such character code ? Any tool or method?

Comment: @HarshBaid I selected the name, asked FF to show the source of the selection, pasted into Emacs and then used a Lisp function that I wrote many years ago to show me the Unicode code point at the location of the combining dot. My function is too big to fit in this comment box and I'm quite certain that there is a built-in function to do this in Emacs now. I'm sure there are methods more convenient to the majority of people than what I did.